# PETSc installation on windows

Tags: c, windows, cygwin, configure

I am trying to install PETSc library on Windows 7 to be used with Visual Studio Express 2008, but I didn't succeed so far.
I installed cygwin (default installation) with python, make, diff.
Then I clicked on

```
VS2008Exp->Tools->VSCommand Prompt
```

I went to the Petsc directory

```
cygdrive/d/Workspace/PETSc/petsc-2.3.3-p13
```

From there I tried
[an official suggestion](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hpctrekker/archive/2008/09/07/running-petsc-on-windows.aspx)

installing first the "Microsoft HPC Pack 2008 R2" and "Microsoft HPC Pack 2008 R2 SDK"
but I had an error "Unable to configure with given options" referring to
--with-mpi-include="/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Microsoft\ HPC\ Pack\ 2008\ SDK/Include"
--with-mpi-lib="/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Microsoft\ HPC\ Pack\ 2008\ SDK/Lib/amd64/msmpi.lib"

Afterwords I tried

```
config/config.py -with-cc="win32fe cl" --with-fc=0 --download-c-blas-lapack=1 --download-mpich=1
```

and now the error  complains about the path for MPI (that I asked to be installed ..).

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Error you described here is about the MSMPI installation path. Since it has space chars configuration utility fails. So you have two options you may install MSMPI on a simple path like C:\MSMPI or use following syntax

```
--with-mpi-include='[my msmpi path]'
```

I am using this for MSMPI;

```
--with-mpi-include=/cygdrive/c/MSMPI/Inc/ --with-mpi-lib='[/cygdrive/c/MSMPI/Lib/amd64/msmpi.lib,/cygdrive/c/MSMPI/Lib/amd64/msmpifec.lib]'
```

For further info you may see this [link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/19oFOjK1B_p2D2ZEvWHVTngno_-g3SPi4PBwcF4mm4Yc/edit)